# Algorithm for efficiently calculating $(A+\sum_{i=1}^n B_i)^{-1}$ where $A^{-1}\in\mathbb S^n_+$ is known and $B_i$ are sparse matrices

Tags: matrices, laplacian, matrix-inverse

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive-definite matrix and $A^{-1}$ is already known. Now I want to compute the matrix $(A+\sum_{i=1}^n B_i)^{-1}$ where each $B_i$ is a sparse symmetric matrix with only four non-zero elements that are placed on the rectangle, which has the following form:
$$B_i=(e_j-e_k)(e_j-e_k)^T=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
 &  &  &  & \\
 & 1 & -1 &  & \\
 &  &  &  & \\
 & -1 & 1 & \\
 & & & &
\end{array}\right]$$
where $e_j$ is the $j$-th unit vector.

Such a problem has many practical values (such as in graph theory). I wonder if there is some algorithm to compute $(A+\sum_{i=1}^n B_i)^{-1}$ in $\Theta(n^2)$ time based on the known matrix $A^{-1}$. I have tried to use the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula:
$$(A+vv^T)^{-1}=A^{-1}-\frac {A^{-1}vv^T A^{-1}}{1+v^T A^{-1} v},$$
but it seems that each iteration has to update the full matrix and the overall complexity remains $\Theta(n^3)$ (which is the same as a direct matrix inversion). Since the summation $\sum_{i=1}^n B_i$ is still highly sparse and the structure of the matrix has a special form, I wonder whether it is possible to calculate the inversion efficiently in $\Theta(n^2)$ time. Thank you!

Comment: Similar issues are well-studied in the context of interior point methods for semidefinite optimisation.

Comment: Can semidefinite optimisation achieve the optimal complexity? To my knowledge, optimization based methods typically give an approximate solution rather than exact one and the complexity depends on the desired error $\epsilon$. Could you please give some reference for related problems? Thank you!

Comment: Is it also true that the summation over B_i's is still such that the number of non-zero rows/columns is subdued by the growth of n?

Comment: Each $B_i$ can have two non-zero rows/columns, so it is possible that all rows/columns of $\sum_i B_i$ are non-zero. But the matrix is still sparse and has no more than 4n elements.

Comment: step directions of path-following (interior-point) methods for semidefinite optimisation are updated in a similar way, not that computing such an $A^{-1}$ is the goal of semidefinite optimisation.